# how to copy(insert) hash reference to another hash reference in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

recently started doing perl. I'm reading old code and trying to rewrite some stuff. I've got a question here about hash references.

```
 #declar anon hash ref that will be returned 
 my $store_hash = {};
 foreach my $item (@list)
 {
     #this will iterate based on list
     my $ret_hash = ops_getval($item, $user)

     #do some magic here to map $ret_hash into $store_hash
 }
```

ops_getval is a function that returns a type of ref hash. I want to insert those values into $store_hash. How should I approach this? Can I directly do

```
$store_hash = ops_getval($var1,$var2)
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: You may consider to loop directly on the properties in the ops_getval($item,$user) instead. May be your code will become much cleaner (?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the standard way to do this is:

```
@$store_hash{ keys %$ret_hash } = values %$ret_hash;
```

This merges all of the hashes returned by all of the calls to `ops_getval` into `$store_hash`.

An alternate approach that might be clearer to the eye, possibly at the cost of a lot of redundant data copying:

```
%$store_hash = (%$store_hash, %$ret_hash);
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the help, I think this is what I need.  Just wondering, what do you mean "at the cost of a lot of redundant data copying" ?   How do these two different ways differ in terms of operation(memory usage, complexity)

Comment: The first method simply inserts the new key-value pairs into $store_hash.  The second method clears out $store_hash at every step and re-creates it with its old contents plus the new contents from $ret_hash.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like:

```
$store_hash->{$item} = $ret_hash
```

In general:

```
$hashref->{$key} = $value
```

See here for more: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References

Comment: thanks, I think I might have said it in a wrong way..I have a hash reference, and I want to duplicate everything from that to another hash reference.   I was wondering if perl has some sort of way of mapping them over.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you can use a loop and get this done.

```
foreach ( keys%{ $ret_hash } ){
      $store_hash->{ $_ } = $ret_hash->{ $_ } ; 
}
```